# How does unordered_set determine the inserting order in c++?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I know that people use `unordered_set` when they don't care about the order of the elements in the set. However, when I run the sample program on [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main()

{
std::unordered_set<std::string> inputSet;
inputSet.insert("Hello world");
inputSet.insert("Abcdef");
inputSet.insert("This is the test string...");

for(const auto &val : inputSet)
  std::cout << val.c_str() << std::endl;

return 0;}
```

it gives me

```
This is the test string...
Abcdef
Hello world
```

And I tried to run it for 3 or 4 times, it still gives me the same output which implies that there is a way that `unordered_set` determine the inserting order.

Can someone explain how does `unordered_set` determine the inserting order?

Sorry if it has been asked before, I've searched online for a while and I cannot find a specific answer to this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know anyway? You should under no circumstances try to rely on the order.

Comment: @mclaassen Sometime we should have curiosity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no specific ordering... It uses the default `std::hash` to hash the string. And whatever the hash value is, it is converted into an appropriate bucket index in the container..

The hash value we are talking about can be gotten:

```
auto hello = std::hash<std::string>()("Hello world");
auto abcd = std::hash<std::string>()("Abcdef");
auto test = std::hash<std::string>()("This is the test string...");
```

For a particular STL implementation, this resolves to:

```
Hello maps to: 14420674105493498572
abcd maps to: 10830572898531769673
test maps to: 13068738153895491918
```

See it Live on [C++Shell](http://cpp.sh/9xocn)

The value is usually converted to an appropriate bucket index by applying `%` operator. Again the `std::unordered_set`'s iterator isn't mandated to sequentially iterate through all the buckets (what about collisions?). So, you should not rely on any ordering you observe from the iterators between program runs.

---

*From C++14, `std::hash<>` is explicitly permitted to produce different results between different program runs. To [quote](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Notes):*

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the
>   same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted
>   hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks.

Comment: When i use bucket method and enter something that i did not put in the unordered set , it still returns some bucket, why is that?

Comment: Also I tried finding bucket of these three, and it came out to be same, but they have different hash??

Answer (score 2):

As stated here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to
>   individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the
>   exact bucket the element is placed into.

So it either uses a default or user provided hash algorithm to sort into hash buckets.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way to predict the output?

Comment: @user2185071 I think the "predictability" of the output depends on: the type (because the type determines the hash value, which is just a number), and the insertion order (because, for values which same hash --unlikely; the order is the same as the insertion order).

Comment: unordered sets are optimized for insertion and retrieval, not traversal. If insertion order is your priority, use a different container.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this same phenomenon. At first I thought it was a quirk of the **cling** compiler; however, upon further investigation, I found this answer: [Complexity of std::unordered_set iterator traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43387247/2288986)

Here it was suggested that the iteration is by *reverse-bucket-creation order*. I ran a test of my own and confirmed this hypothesis.

**`test.cpp`**

```cpp
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <unordered_set>
using std::unordered_set;

int main() {
    unordered_set<string> stuff(10);
    stuff.insert("yep");
    stuff.insert("123");
    stuff.insert("xyz");
    stuff.insert("foo");
    stuff.insert("bar");
    stuff.insert("baz");
    stuff.insert("abc");

    for (const auto& word : stuff) {
        cout << word << endl;
    }

    cout << "bucket count: " << stuff.bucket_count() << endl;

    cout << "yep: " << stuff.bucket("yep") << endl;
    cout << "123: " << stuff.bucket("123") << endl;
    cout << "xyz: " << stuff.bucket("xyz") << endl;
    cout << "foo: " << stuff.bucket("foo") << endl;
    cout << "bar: " << stuff.bucket("bar") << endl;
    cout << "baz: " << stuff.bucket("baz") << endl;
    cout << "abc: " << stuff.bucket("abc") << endl;
}
```

```bash
% g++ -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp && ./test
abc
baz
foo
bar
xyz
123
yep
bucket count: 11
yep: 8
123: 10
xyz: 9
foo: 5
bar: 9
baz: 6
abc: 3
```

As the buckets are *created*, they (their indexex) are (likely) pushed to the front of a singly-linked list (which iterates in *reverse insertion order*: 3, 6, 5, 9, 10, 8.

Note: the buckets are also SLLists (and thus iterate in reverse-insertion order; this is why `bar` comes before `xyz` in bucket `9` below).

So the iteration happens:

```
3)  abc
6)  baz
5)  foo
9)  bar, xyz
10) 123
8)  yep
```

So if you have no collisions when adding your items (and your table doesn't grow) then you will have reverse-insertion order.

But if you insert more items and the table grows (and all the items are re-inserted), then your iteration order will reflect the reverse-bucket-creation order of the re-inserted items (and my guess is the items are inserted in order of iteration; so the more you insert and the more the table grows, the obfuscated the original insertion order becomes).

Answer (score 0):

The order in an `std::unordered_set<T>` is, well, unordered. However, assuming a deterministic hash is used and the same order of insert operations is done, different runs of a program will have the elements in the same order. Inserting the elements in a different order and/or using a hash which produces different values for different runs will produce a different order of the elements.